# jquery .each() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to loop through

- each object within `lists` and then
- each `list` within `lists` and count the number of objects within `list`
- if the number of objects within `list` = 3, I want to alert the value of each object

**JSON**

```
{
   "lists":[
    {
        "list":[
         {
            "value": "List 1 Value A"
         },
         {
            "value": "List 1 Value B"
         },
         {
            "value": "List 1 Value C"
         }
       ]
    },
    {
         "list":[
          {
             "value": "List 2 Value A"
          },
          {
             "value": "List 2 Value B"
          },
          {
             "value": "List 2 Value C"
          },
          {
             "value": "List 2 Value D"
          }
         ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**JQuery Code**

```
$.each(response.lists.list, function(index, list){
   alert(list.value);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```
$.each(response.lists, function (i, list) {
    if (list.list.length === 3) {
        $.each(list.list, function (j, item) {
            alert(item.value);
        });
    }
});
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BNEwu/)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot some of the requirements. I've updated my post.

Comment: @SK11 - Just add an if statement around the inner each that checks the size of `list`.

Answer (score 0):

First try it without jQuery.each. You will need a loop, an if-statement and another loop.

```
for (var i=0; i<response.lists.length; i++)
    if (response.lists[i].list.length == 3)
        for (var j=0; j<response.lists[i].list.length)
            alert(response.lists[i].list[j].value);
```

I hope there is a good reason to use objects with properties (`lists`, `list`, `value`); otherwise it could be very much simpler by using only arrays.

Now then, the above loop construct with `forEach`:

```
 $.each(response.lists, function(index, item) {
     if (item.list.length == 3)
         $.each(member.list, function(index, item) {
             alert(item.value);
         });
 });
```